# Strange behavior of strlen(), giving different output when used at different place in code

Tags: c++

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char ch[10];
        std::cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        std::cout<<"Enter the string: ";
        gets(ch);
        std::cout<<strlen(ch)<<"\n";
        std::cout<<ch<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"sizeof ch"<<sizeof(ch)<<"\n";
        int len=strlen(ch);
        std::cout<<strlen(ch)<<"\n";
        std::cout<<len<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"second last="<<ch[len-1]<<" last="<<(int)ch[len]<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        return 0;
}
```

```
OUTPUT:

 1. On giving input within defined range(i.e less than 10)

Enter the string: 12345678
8
12345678
sizeof ch10
8
8
second last=8 last=0

 2. On giving input beyond defined range

Enter the string: 12345678901234
14
12345678901234
sizeof ch10
13
14
second last= last=0



Enter the string: 123456789012345678
18
123456789012345678
sizeof ch10
13
18
second last=8 last=0
```

I know use of gets should not be used but still i want to learn what is happening inside, why third last line of output is giving 13 ??

Answer (score 5):

The only real answer is undefined behaviour. Once you access memory beyond the end of the array, as `gets` does if the input is too large, anything could happen.

If I had to guess: the most likely explanation is that the compiler placed `len` after `ch` in memory. So assigning to `len` would overwrite some of the input that spilled off the end of the array. Some of the bytes of that value will be zero (since it's a small number), so the next call to `strlen` will stop when it finds one of those bytes, giving a small value than before.

Perhaps the memory layout looks like this, before and after assigning to `len`. I'm assuming ASCII encoding, so `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49, etc. I'm assuming that `int` has four bytes, arranged in "little-endian" order with the least significant first in memory, and needs to be aligned on a four-byte boundary, requiring two padding bytes to store it after the array.

```
| ch, 10 bytes                  | pad   | len, 4 bytes| other    |
| 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 48 | 49 50 | 51 52 53 54 | 55 56 00 | before
| 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 48 | 49 50 | 18 00 00 00 | 55 56 00 | after
```

You can see that calling `strlen` a second time in this situation will find 13 characters before a zero-valued byte is interpreted as the end of the string. This matches your observation.

As you say, never use `gets` since there's no way to avoid or even reliably detect a buffer overrun. Be very careful with fixed-size arrays, and prefer more friendly C++ idioms to C-style memory juggling. Using `std::string` would avoid this fiasco entirely.

Comment: Thank you Mike, i also think that your observation is correct to great extent. I will clarify the same practically :)